# on_failure_callback is executed only at task level but not on DAG level

Tags: python, airflow

This is a sample code, trying to test `on_failure_callback` at dag level. It works when I explicitly call out at task level but not at dag level.

following DAG level code doesn't call `on_failure_callback`

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def on_failure(ctx):
    print('hello world')
    print(ctx)

def always_fails():
    sys.exit(1)

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='always_fails',
    description='dag that always fails',
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    start_date=datetime(2021,7,12),
    on_failure_callback=on_failure
)

task = PythonOperator(task_id='test-error-notifier', python_callable=always_fails, dag=dag)
```

This is task level code which is calling `on_failure_callback --> on_failure`.

```
PythonOperator(task_id='test-error-notifier', python_callable=always_fails, 
on_failure_callback=on_failure,
dag=dag)
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK, it does call it, but the logs are a bit hard to find. Search for the string "hello world" in the `logs/scheduler/` directory, see if you find it there? Also, there's a difference between `DAG(... on_failure_callback=func` (where `func` is run when the DagRun changes state to `FAILED`) and `DAG(... default_args={'on_failure_callback': func...)` which applies to when the tasks change state to `FAILED`... And I'm like... 99.99% sure of this... or... 98%... or... 63% 

Comment: @Savir : Thanks for getting back. That make sense. I use AWS MWAA so I dont see a way to access the logs directory but I will test it by writing some email function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define it in the default_args:

Setting on_failure_callback at the DAG level applies to the DagRun failing not tasks specifically.

```
dag = DAG(
dag_id='always_fails',
description='dag that always fails',
schedule_interval=None,
catchup=False,
start_date=datetime(2021, 7, 12),
default_args={
    "on_failure_callback": on_failure
}
)

task = PythonOperator(task_id='test-error-notifier', python_callable=always_fails, dag=dag)
```

Comment: This one works and I could see the logs at task level now even though default arg set at dag level

Comment: Do you know why it works this way? Because this conflicts heavily with the example provided by Airflow: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.8.1/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html#example - which implies that defining the callbacks in DAG level, will still trigger whenever any task fails.

Comment: @QuanBui, maybe its wrong document. you can see in the code that the write that this callback is exeucte when DagRun fails (A function or list of functions to be called when a DagRun of this dag fails): https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v2-8-stable/airflow/models/dag.py